# show loader using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.loader_bg').fadeToggle();
    }, 1500);

</script>

<div class="loader_bg">
    <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

I have a loader in my website . I want to show a loader for 1.5 sec to user till page fully load  have achieved somewhat to this through j query but  want it in pure javascript as haven't use any j query through out the project

Comment: FWIW, showing the loader for a predetermined, hardcoded length of time is something of an antipattern: what happens if the user is on a slow connection, and it takes them six seconds before the site loads?  They will see a broken/incomplete page after your loader disappears.  And if they have a very fast connection, and your page loads for them in 200ms, you are forcing them to wait an additional 1.3 seconds for no reason.  It would be better to try to detect when your page is actually loaded and _then_ hid the spinner.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function show_loader() {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/150';
  img.className = 'loader';
  img.id = 'image';
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
show_loader();

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("image").classList.add('loaderOut');
}, 3000);
```

```css
.loader {
  display: block;
}

.loaderOut {
  display: none;
}
```